# How to create a div at centre of a page with search box and below that images(2x3) in 2 rows and 3 columns using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a page which has a search box at centre of the page and below that i need to display some 6 thumbnail images in 2 rows and 3 columns using bootstrap framework.

Note:The whole page content should be present at centre of the page

Comment: I agree with Adsy, Please show us some code/image that have you tried or you want to do.

Comment: you can look up the code here - seems to be the same question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606084/bootstrap-col-is-not-displaying-at-the-center-of-the-page-at-time-of-resizing

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class=" container col-md-12 col-xs-12 abc">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Keyword">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Search</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="container col-md-12 abc">
              <img src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.jpg&text=Dummy+Image" class="image col-md-4 col-xs-4">
              <img src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.jpg&text=Dummy+Image" class="image col-md-4 col-xs-4">
              <img src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.jpg&text=Dummy+Image" class="image col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    </div>
    <div class="container col-md-12 abc">
              <img src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.jpg&text=Dummy+Image" class="image col-md-4 col-xs-4">
              <img src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.jpg&text=Dummy+Image" class="image col-md-4 col-xs-4">
              <img src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.jpg&text=Dummy+Image" class="image col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    </div>
```

You just add an extra style in css :

```
.abc{
    padding : 20px;
}
```

And this is the most simplest way and the most perfect way to do this. Working all fine. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use offset class with the search controls and thumbnails.For example:

```
<div class="offsetX">
//Search control.
</div>
```

X can be number 1-12

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Code below is with bootstrap 3.0

```
 <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search term">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><img src="http://www.bio.umass.edu/micro/nusslein/images/people/no_photo.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><img src="http://www.bio.umass.edu/micro/nusslein/images/people/no_photo.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><img src="http://www.bio.umass.edu/micro/nusslein/images/people/no_photo.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><img src="http://www.bio.umass.edu/micro/nusslein/images/people/no_photo.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><img src="http://www.bio.umass.edu/micro/nusslein/images/people/no_photo.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><img src="http://www.bio.umass.edu/micro/nusslein/images/people/no_photo.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```