# bootstrap col is not displaying at the center of the page at time of resizing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

At certain resolution nearly from 1020px the bootstrap col which i have centred using offset is not working properly.How to resolve this issue..

```html
<section id="content" class="m-t-lg" style="margin-top:100px;"> 
   <a class="nav-brand" href="#">My Home page</a>
  <div class="row m-n">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 m-t">

      <form class="m-t-lg" role="search" >
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control input-lg no-border bg-dark" type="text" placeholder="Search">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit"> <i class="icon-search"></i> </button>
          </span> </div>
      </form>
      <center>
     <section class="panel-body">
      <div class="row m-n m-t"><h4 align="center">Heading1</h4>
        <ul class="pull-left">
          <li class="list-inline pull-left m-r-sm"> <a href="#"><img src="images/img_2.png" alt="img" class="img-responsive"></a> </li>
          <li class="list-inline pull-left m-r-sm"> <a href="#"><img src="images/img_2.png" alt="img" class="img-responsive"></a> </li>
          <li class="list-inline pull-left m-r-sm"> <a href="#"><img src="images/img_2.png" alt="img" class="img-responsive"></a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </section>

              <section class="panel-body">
       <h4 align="center">Heading2</h4>

        <ul "pull-left">
          <li class="list-inline pull-left  m-r-sm"> <a href="#"><img src="images/img_2.png" alt="img"></a> </li>
          <li class="list-inline pull-left  m-r-sm"> <a href="#"><img src="images/img_2.png" alt="img"></a> </li>
          <li class="list-inline pull-left  m-r-sm"> <a href="#"><img src="images/img_2.png" alt="img"></a> </li>
        </ul>
        </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code --> http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry i was not able to create a fiddle.we are working in a template which is using bootstrap framework.its not possible to link all css. Actually we are displaying the content in centre of page using col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 but its not working properly while resizing the screen.

Comment: What are those m-n and m-t classes? Probably has to do with it...

Comment: Created a fiddle for you (with fixing some markup errors) http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/427/ . Please tell us, what exactly is not working properly and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've improved on @kkern's fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/478/ removed the center element and added font-awsome. still can't see what's wrong or meant to be right

Answer (score 3):

Unless you didn't include it with your example, you're missing a Bootstrap 101 rule.

> Rows must be placed within a **.container** for proper alignment and padding.

Based on your example, wrapping your `<section>` tag with a `<div class="container">` will help.  I was unable to replicate any issue that you seem to be experiencing and must point out that @kkern may have solved the issue without realizing the container was missing in your stack example.

```
<div class="container">
   <section id="content" class="m-t-lg" style="margin-top:100px;">
   ........
```